# if $\{x_n\}\subseteq A$ and $x_n\to L,$ can I conclude that $L=\sup A$?

Tags: calculus

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. I know that if $m:=\sup A$, then exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq A$ such that $x_n\to m$.

Now, if we found a sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq A$ such that $x_n\to L\in [0,\infty]$ can I conclude that $L=\sup A$?

Comment: No - Take $A = [0, 1]$ and the sequence $\left( \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right)_n.$

Comment: Consider $A=(0, 2]$ and $x_n=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: This is very far from being true! If it were true, you could take _any_ $a\in A$, set $x_n=a$ for all $n$, and conclude that $\sup A=a$.

Comment: Did you want to add that the sequence is monotonically increasing? This could be easily disproved if the sequence is decreasing on $A$.

Comment: @bb_823: that doesn't help. E.g. $A=[0,10], x_n = 1-1/2^n$.

Comment: @TonyK yeah, you're right I'm guessing there should also be some condition for $A$, such that $A=[\inf\{x_n\},\sup\{x_n\}]$.

Comment: @bb_823: OP's whole idea is nonsense, I'm afraid.

Comment: The quantity $\sup A$ depends on $x_1$ unlike $\lim x_n.$

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not true by any means. Given a particular set $A$ you can even take a larger set $B$ with $A \subset B$, then $\{x_n\} \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2):

No! It is easy to find counterexamples. For instance, consider $A = [0,1]$ and let $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence decreasing to $0$ - for example, $x_n = 1/n$. Clearly, $$x_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0 \ne 1 = \sup A$$

In fact, if $\varnothing \ne A \subset \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, then the condition that for every sequence $\{x_n\} \subset A$ with $x_n \to L$ implies $L = \sup A$ , forces $A$ to be a singleton. To show this, consider a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset A$ converging to $\inf A$.